# Rust implementing a simple prime numbers collection given a range of numbers

Tags: rust

I know there's probably a prime standard built-in function but my point here is learning rust lang.

The goal of this function is to get a collection of prime numbers given a range of numbers.

```
fn main() -> () {
    let n = 1..20;
    let primes: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    for val in n {
        primes.push( (1..20).filter(|x| x / val == 1 && x % val == 0).collect() );
        println!("we got: {}", primes[val-1]);
    }
// expecting primes to be [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]
}
```

compiler complains about

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:5:22
  |
5 |         primes.push( (1..20).filter(|x| x / val == 1 && x % val == 0) );
  |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected u32, found struct `std::iter::Filter`
  |
  = note: expected type `u32`
             found type `std::iter::Filter<std::ops::Range<{integer}>, [closure@src/main.rs:5:37: 5:69 val:_]>`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

what I'm doing wrong here? I'm having hard time with all that ownership, referencing and lifetime thingy

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do exactly. Why do you have a loop over `1..20` and then you're also filtering over `1..20`? What is the filter's purpose? What is the intent of the filter's logic? Can you describe what is the intent of each iteration of the for loop

Comment: filter intent is to filter out non prime numbers and collect prime numbers in primes vec

Comment: So at **every** iteration, you wish to add **all** prime number from `1..20` into `primes`. Wouldn't that give you a `Vec` of `Vec`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push` can only push a single element onto a vector, e.g.

```
primes.push(2);
```

However, `collect()` doesn't yield a single element here; instead, it [yields a collection that implements `FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect).

To `extend` a `Vec` by the contents of an iterator, we use its [`Extend` implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html) instead:

```
primes.extend((1..20).filter(|x| x / val == 1 && x % val == 0));
```

Note that `collect` is missing now.

That being said, both `extend` and `push` need a `mut Vec`, so make sure to make `primes` mutable. Also keep in mind that your current code yields the wrong result, as it will add all numbers; that's not a Rust problem, however, but an algorithm one.

Comment: yes algorithm is totally wrong, just experimenting, thx for the quick reply